# Synonymize or blacklist [vanilla-js] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There has been a website in the past, about "vanilla-js" (http://vanilla-js.com/) because of the multiple open source libraries/frameworks got founded during that period. That was not something serious. Just a "gag". There is a "legitimate" SO question about that here: [What is VanillaJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435653/what-is-vanillajs)

Yet, when reviewing the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20435653/revisions) you can see that [vanilla-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-js) got added and removed several times. It occurred again today.

That tag thing has been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221687/should-there-be-a-vanilla-javascript-tag)

### WANT

synonymising "vanillajs" / "vanilla-js" to [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) so that this does not occur anymore. Or blacklist it.

Answer (score 13):

One of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)'s synonyms is [vanilla-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-javascript), so having an additional [vanilla-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-js) synonym seems like a no-brainer. Done.

Comment: Done in 3 minutes, is this a new record?

Comment: Did you also add `vanillajs`? That one was in the question's history as well (and slightly hidden in this request)

Comment: @Cerbrus: I wasn't sure if all hyphenated forms were considered for the purposes of each synonym, but I've just gone ahead and added that, just in case.

Comment: Not sure if you fancy doing a similar quick job on this? [Synonymize or blacklist \[vanilla\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403773/synonymize-or-blacklist-vanilla-tag)

Comment: @Liam: Thanks. Mods cannot blacklist tags, only employees can. But I'll leave a comment.