# Synonymize or blacklist [vanilla] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

It seems someone has created a [vanilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla) in reference to Vanilla Javascript, which isn't a thing. The language is Javascript, We don't have vanilla-c# or Vanilla-Java so it makes no sense to have vanilla js or the [vanilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla) at all. This is related to this question [Synonymize or blacklist [vanilla-js] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375157/synomize-or-blacklist-vanilla-js-tag), so I'll repeat some of the arguments from that here:

> There has been a website in the past, about "vanilla-js"
> (http://vanilla-js.com/) because of the multiple open source
> libraries/frameworks got founded during that period. That was not
> something serious. Just a "gag". There is a "legitimate" SO question
> about that here: What is VanillaJS?

and also the [response from Bolt-clock:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375158/542251)

> One of javascript's synonyms is vanilla-javascript, so having an
> additional vanilla-js synonym seems like a no-brainer. Done.

I propose that the [vanilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla) is **blacklisted** to "so that this does not occur anymore".

Comment: This burninate request is pretty vanilla.

Comment: I would be against having "vanilla" being a synonym for "vanilla-javascript". It should be blacklisted, like you also suggested.

Comment: Happy with either TBH, so long as it dies... :)

Comment: Just worth pointing out that all the questions tagged with this also have the [tag:javascript] tag. It seems to be a persistent myth that there is such a thing as vanilla Javascript, I blame Jquery

Comment: I always thought "vanilla JavaScript" was just used to refer to using JS without any extra frameworks... but that's pretty ambiguous now that I think about it.

Comment: It is, @zcoop98. But it's a nonsense term. The name for Javascript without any frameworks is Javascript.

Comment: Agree with blacklist, it's not going to work as a synonym because there are so many different things called Vanilla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[vanilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vanilla) is now blocklisted.